# "OkHttpClient cannot be converted to MyOkHttpClient"

Tags: java, okhttp

Why wont this compile:

```
MyOkHttpClient okClient = new MyOkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor()).build();
```

Incompatible types.
Required:
my.path.util.auth.MyOkHttpClient
Found:
okhttp3.OkHttpClient

This is MY class:

```
public class MyOkHttpClient extends okhttp3.OkHttpClient implements Authenticator {

    private static int MAX_AUTHENTICATE_TRIES = 3;



    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        if (responseCount(response) >= MAX_AUTHENTICATE_TRIES) {
            return null; // If we've failed 3 times, give up. - in real life, never give up!!
        }
        String credential = Credentials.basic(AUTHTOKEN_USERNAME, AUTHTOKEN_PASSWORD);
        return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
    }

    private int responseCount(Response response) {
        int result = 1;
        while ((response = response.priorResponse()) != null) {
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: You only extended the outer class. You did not extend the Builder. As an aside, what is it that you are attempting to accomplish here? There doesn't appear to be a reason for you to be extending OkHttpClient at all.

Comment: I cannot extend OkthhpClient.Builder .... is there another way around this?

Comment: Yeah. Don't do this. Things that implement the Builder pattern are typically hard to extend, because they weren't really meant to be.

Comment: I'm Overriding authenticate(Route route, Response response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you incorrectly believe that you are decorating OkHttpClient with custom authentication logic.

Instead, you are unnecessarily extending OkHttpClient *and* implementing the `Authenticator` interface. You can simply build the standard OkHttpClient with any custom authenticator you would like.

As such, *this* is more like what you actually want

```
public class MyAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    private static int MAX_AUTHENTICATE_TRIES = 3;

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        if (responseCount(response) >= MAX_AUTHENTICATE_TRIES) {
            return null; // If we've failed 3 times, give up. - in real life, never give up!!
        }
        String credential = Credentials.basic(AUTHTOKEN_USERNAME, AUTHTOKEN_PASSWORD);
        return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
    }

    private int responseCount(Response response) {
        int result = 1;
        while ((response = response.priorResponse()) != null) {
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

And then when you build your client

```
OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor())
            .authenticator(new MyAuthenticator())
            .build();
```